# delisting my old URL's from copyright services

Tags: redirects, url, content, copyright, copy

About a month ago, I redid a major part of my website so that the difference between thousands of URL's is the subdomain name itself.

Now I go on copyscape and put in my new URL and it tells me that my new content has been duplicated, and the offending URL is the old URL that when accessed, is redirected to the URL I'm inquiring on. This image is a snapshot of the results on copyscape taken moments ago:

[image]

I feel now I need to contact a bunch of companies such as copyscape to have this and other similar listings removed from their database, and If I take no action soon, I feel another robot will come after my site. Google has already done a good job at making my income extremely low so far.

So how do I go about removing my own old URL's from copyright services (including copyscape)? Is there a central URL I could use for all this? or do I have to find and contact every company individually?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to contact anybody. If you setup 301 redirects in your .htaccess file to the new pages correctly there will be no issues with duplicate content.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested before I even posted the question, yet copyscape still claims both pages are duplicates. Google doesn't have issues with copied pages tho. Could it be that these copyright checkers have caches that last indefinitely?

Comment: Most likely that is the case. I would just wait a little while. Plus, these sites don't have a say in how you rank and they can't penalize you for anything. As long as google sees your 301's you have nothing to worry about.